# Label Content Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, string-formatting

Let's say I have a .resx file with a resource key `GroupBoxHeaderCaption` and value "SomeString".

Then in my *ViewModel* I have a `string` property called `Description`.

What I want to achieve is this (given the .resx file is referred to with `using resx = [...]` and the view model is called `viewModel`):

```
string.Format("{0}: {1}", resx.GroupBoxHeaderCaption, viewModel.Description)
```

Is it possible to do this in XAML? I got this, but it's not working:

```
    <GroupBox Margin="4">
        <GroupBox.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label>
                    <Label.Content>
                        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}: {1}">
                            <Binding Path="{x:Static my:MyResources.GroupBoxHeaderCaption}" />
                            <Binding Path="viewModel.Description" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Label.Content>
                </Label>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GroupBox.HeaderTemplate>
```

By *not working* I mean I get `GroupBoxHeaderCaption` red-underlined with an error that says:

> **Invalid member type: expected type is 'PropertyPath', actual type is 'string'.**

I know I could write a converter for my `viewModel.Description`, but is there a way to do this all-XAML?

---

I get the desired result when I do this:

```
<GroupBox Margin="4" Header="{Binding viewModel.Description}" 
                     HeaderStringFormat="SomeString: {0}">
```

I want to fetch the "SomeString:" part from a .resx file.

Comment: Have you set the `Access Modifier` property to `Public` in the resources designer window in Visual Studio, eg. made your resources publicly accessible?

Comment: Yes, absolutely - I'm using this resource file elsewhere in the XAML without any problem, it's just I'd like to combine a resource string with a view model property and I'm wondering if a binding StringFormat can do that. It looks like it won't work off a *string*, it wants a string *property*...

Comment: It's like in those examples where they give something like `StringFormat="{}Cost: {0}"` - well I want the "Cost:" part to be taken from a .resx file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just worked out why you're getting that error. It's because you can't refer to the resource `string` like that in the `Path` property of that `MultiBinding`.

I think that maybe you have to try something like this:

```
<MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}: {1}">
    <Binding Path="GroupBoxHeaderCaption" Source="{x:Static my:MyResources}" />
    <Binding Path="viewModel.Description" />
</MultiBinding>
```

Unfortunately, I can't try this out now and I'm not sure if this is the correct syntax, so please come back and let me know if you have further problems.

Comment: Haven't tried yet, but from the looks of it, your referring to the string *property* in the resource file, rather than directly to the *string* itself, looks promosing.

Comment: ...unfortunately `Source="{x:Static my:MyResources}"` fails, saying "StaticExtension must have a member specified."...

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense... ok failing that, how about adding a property to your view model and setting its value from the resource in code and then `Binding` with the property?

Comment: That was my exact initial thought, but then does it mean there's no way 100% XAML/StringFormat can do that?

Comment: I wouldn't say that... I'd imagine that there *is* a way to set a resource file as a `Binding.Source`, but I just can't find one after a quick search.

Comment: Then that's what this question is after :)  thanks for your input, feel free to edit your answer when you find out, I'll accept the answer that either proves it's not possible, or that shows how it can be achieved.

Comment: I give up... ViewModel property it is then :)